# Change the value which is in next column of the value dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas data frame like this..

```
   user    pwd    _message_  
0 _robin_ | usi | _I like coffee_  
1 _priya_ | ind | _I like green tea_  
2 gate    | ldn | _I like to play_  
3 _Reh_   | ksm | _I respect others_
```

I have value "ksm", and I want to change the value of next column of it and in the same row. it means I want to change "I respect others" to "I love myself". I have searched about it but I could not find straight forward way to do this task. 
Is there is any straight forward way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataFrame.loc ,i.e.  label-location based indexer for selection by label. this will help you avoid 'on the copy of ...' warning

```
df.loc[df.pwd=='ksm', 'message'] = 'I love myself'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could filter on `pwd` and assign the constant to all matching `message` elements:

```
df
# value before:
    user  pwd           message
0  robin  usi     I like coffee
1  priya  ind  I like green tea
2   gate  ldn    I like to play
3    Reh  ksm  I respect others

df['message'][df.pwd=='ksm'] = 'I love myself'
df
# output after
    user  pwd           message
0  robin  usi     I like coffee
1  priya  ind  I like green tea
2   gate  ldn    I like to play
3    Reh  ksm     I love myself
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.index` to find the row number that corresponds to `pwd = ksm`:

```
rowIndx = df.index[df['pwd'] == 'ksm']
```

Then you can use that index to change the value of the `_message_` column at that row:

```
df['_message_'][rowIndx] = 'I love myself'
```